# How to remove org- ID drawer + location file entry

Tags: org-mode

What is the reverse method of `org-id-get-create` -- i.e., remove the ID property drawer and also remove the corresponding entry in the `org-id-locations-file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-id-get-create` calls `org-id-get`, which calls `org-id-add-location`, which updates the global `org-id-locations` hash-table.  This does not automatically update the `org-id-locations-file`.  I have chosen to add `org-id-locations-save` to a custom version of `org-id-get` -- just after the call to `org-id-add-location`.  However, that is not mission critical since there are other methods such as the `kill-emacs-hook` that trigger `org-id-locations-save`.  [I simply want my database updated forthwith.]

The following function will remove the `ID` property drawer and update both the `org-id-locations` hash-table and the `org-id-locations-file`.

```lisp
(defun org-id-remove-entry ()
"Remove/delete the ID entry and update the databases.
Update the `org-id-locations' global hash-table, and update the
`org-id-locations-file'.  `org-id-track-globally' must be `t`."
(interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (when (org-entry-delete (point) "ID")
      (org-id-update-id-locations nil 'silent))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked how to remove, I have been happy hiding it with this config:

```
(setq org-id-locations-file "/path/to/state-directory")
```